# Antecedent Noun After The Relative Clause

Tags: relative-clause

Calcidius on Plato's Timaeus, 276:

> Omnia tamen haec in unum aiunt concurrere, ut et generata sit **ea** *quae subiecta est universo corpori* **silva [=materia]**

The English translation:

> In all this, they (the Jews) say, they agree that **matter**, underlying all bodies, was generated

I could not find this structure in grammar books:

> demonstrative pronoun + relative clause + antecedent noun

There are almost similar examples in A&G 307b, such as:

> quae **grātia** currum fuit vīvīs, **eadem** sequitur

But I am not sure it corresponds to the above text. Please refer me to a source on this structure.

Comment: I'd suggest the following replacement: demonstrative pronoun + relative clause + antecedent noun > demonstrative _determiner_ (traditionally, "demonstrative _adjective_") + relative clause + _postcedent_ noun

Comment: @Mitomino Shouldn't it be *succedent noun*?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel In my opinion, both terms ("postcedent" and "succedent") are appropriate here. I'm not sure about the English grammatical tradition but it seems that the term that is more often used is "postcedent" (e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)#Postcedents ).

Comment: @Mitomino I am being a little facetiously over-pedantic, but the problem with *postcedent* is that there's no such verb as *postcedere*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That the antecedent noun follows the relative clause happens occasionally. In this case the demonstrative adjective and the noun are separated, which is an example of [hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton#Latin), and hyperbata are quite common in Latin.

Here is Cicero in [*De officiis* 1, 69](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0047%3Abook%3D1%3Asection%3D69):

> Multi autem et sunt et fuerunt, qui **eam,** quam dico, **tranquillitatem** expetentes a negotiis publicis se removerint …

Rather similar also [*Brutus* 83, 287](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0544%3Achapter%3D83%3Asection%3D287):

> At quid est tam fractum, tam minutum, tam in **ipsa**, quam tamen consequitur, **concinnitate** puerile?

I would not expect ordinary grammar books to give examples of every possible word order around relative clauses. That said, [this Austrian website](https://www.latein-grammatik.at/Relativsatz.htm#Besonderheiten_des_Relativsatzes) explicitly mentions the possibility of the relative clause being “embedded” in the main clause, and was my source for the first Cicero quote. In this view, this is just a particular case of the more general idea of embedding, like Caesar, Bellum Gallicum 1, 1:

> minimeque ad eos mercatores saepe commeant atque ea quae ad effeminandos animos pertinent important

We could also imagine ***eas**, quae ad effeminandos animos pertinent **merces** important*.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd qualify this case as an example of hyperbaton. BTW, the link to this Austrian website is very useful! _Longum iter per praecepta, breve et eficax per exempla_.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: In Cicero's "de Officiis" 1.69; looking at the whole (long) sentence, why deploy (perfect) subjunctives, "removerint" & "perfugerint", as opposed to indicative verbs?

Comment: @tony I'd say subjunctive of characteristic, common with *multi sunt* and similar phrases.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a follow-up answer to the excellent one provided by Sebastian Koppehel. He is probably right when saying "I would not expect ordinary grammar books to give examples of every possible word order around relative clauses". For topics like the one at issue here, it can be useful to take a look at "unordinary grammar books". For example, I've just seen that in the 2nd volume of his monumental *The Oxford Latin Syntax*, Pinkster (2021: 497) deals with this syntactic phenomenon and provides some interesting examples. Here is the relevant quote (italics and bold are his) excerpted from Section 18.12 "The relative order of the adnominal relative clause and its head":

> "The relative clause may also be enclosed between a determiner and its head. Examples are (d)–(g). Note that in theory *quem* in (f) could be taken as the determiner of *numerum*, the whole clause (and in that analysis, autonomous) being determined by *eum*, as in the second relative construction of (g). For more examples of this construction, see § 18.16.

> (d) . . . exponit *ea* **quibus** abundabat *plurima et pulcherrima vasa argentea*... (‘. . . he set out those most lovely and numerous silver vessels, of which he had an ample stock.’ Cic. *Ver*. 4.62)

> (e) Discessu Liburnarum ex Illyrico M. Octavius cum *iis* **quas** habebat *navibus* Salonas pervenit. (‘At the departure of the Liburnian ships from Illyricum, Marcus Octavius went to Salonae with the ships he had available.’ Caes. *Civ.* 3.9.1)

> (f) . . . atque *eum* **quem** supra demonstravimus *numerum* expleverat. (‘. . . and had thus filled up the number I stated above.’ Caes. *Civ.* 3.4.6)

> (g) At ii qui in iugo constiterant . . . neque in *eo* **quod** probaverant *consilio* permanere, ut se loco superiore defenderent, neque *eam* **quam** profuisse aliis *vim celeritatemque* viderant imitari potuerunt . . . (‘But the part which had taken post on the ridge . . . could neither abide by the plan that they had approved, namely that they would defend themselves on higher ground, nor could they imitate the vigour and the speed which they had seen to be of assistance to others . . .’ Caes. *Gal.* 6.40.6)

> **Supplement**:
> . . . pro meis in vos singularibus studiis proque *hac* **quam** perspicitis ad conservandam rem publicam *diligentia* ... (Cic. *Catil.* 4.23); ... *ea* ipsa de **qua** disputare ordimur *eloquentia* obmutuit. (Cic. *Brut.* 22); ... celeriter ad *eas* **quas** diximus *munitiones* pervenerunt ... (Caes. *Gal.* 3.26.2); *Ea* **quae** secuta est *hieme* ... Usipetes Germani et item Tenctheri magna multitudine hominum flumen Rhenum transierunt ... (Caes. *Gal.* 4.1.1); En illa, *illa* **quam** saepe optastis *libertas* ... (Sal. *Cat.* 20.14); ... *illa* **quae** iniuria depulsa fuerat *ancilla* totam faciem eius fuligine larga perfricuit ... (Petr. 22.1)

Comment: I had tried to find this structure in Pinkster 2021 but I had not succeeded. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very nice. Pinkster (or perhaps Hofmann-Szantyr) is indeed the sort of unordinary, or even extraordinary grammar book I had in mind when I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian Koppehel's answer is correct. I would like to add that Reginaldus Foster, the rather eccentric, but by all accounts effective, educator devotes the better part of a chapter of his first year text book to exactly this issue, which can easily trip up new students whose native language is English.

His textbook is called *Ossa Latinitatis Sola* (the mere bones of Latin). His chapter Experience 1, Encounter 11 *Pronomen Relativum: Brevitas, Antedentis Omissio, Ordo* begins, "Contact with Latin literature will convince anyone and everyone of how the Romans loved to deal with and hear the relative pronoun."

Later he continues, "After reading out loud several paragraphs of Latin literature from all ages, the first thing that must strike the reader is the location of both the relative pronoun and the relative clause within the overall discourse. Namely, the Romans, because of the freedom of their sentence structure and style, loved to put the relative clause locally in front of the word it describes, which it anticipates. While this is nearly impossible to do in English, the Romans love it..."

He gives quite a few examples. Here are a few:

*Quem misisti perutilis est liber.* (The book, which you sent, is very useful.)

*Quae venerant nos salutaverunt.* (The women who had come greeted us.)

*Quae audivisti falsa sunt.* (The things you have heard are false.)

*Quas laudas, honoro*. (I honor the women you are praising.)

*Qui tibi scribo, benevolentia significo*. (I, who am writing to you, make known my good will.)

Much more discussion and many more examples round out this chapter. As Foster points out this sort of construction is confusing when you first encounter it, but you will quickly get used to it with a bit of practice.